# align li in ul right, center, left then center again

Tags: css

I have a list and I want the first li to be aligned to the right, the 2nd and 4th to the center and the 3rd to the left.

But when i use float right the 2nd li goes up on the same line as the first.

How do I keep the 2nd element from going up?

Comment: pls share your fiddle code

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) to set the alignment.

To select each list item, you can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector.

```css
li { /* or `li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(4)` */
  text-align: center;
}
li:nth-child(1) { /* or `li:first-child` */
  text-align: right;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) on the parent in this case [`menu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) to center all li elements, then [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to float what ever you want.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
menu{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0
}
menu li{
display: inline-block;
max-width: 20%;
background: #ccc;
padding: 10px 24px;
margin: 10px 4px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #808080;
}
menu li:first-child{float: right}
menu li:nth-child(3){float: left}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>WORK</li>
  <li>CONTACT</li>
  <li>INFO</li>
</menu>
```